# How to generate a Div to fill a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We are looking for a solution, to generate a DIV, if our products dont fill up the whole row. We are using a jQuery filter and sort plugin called MixItUp.

Is there a JavaScript solution that recognizes the free space in a row and automatically generates the missing div to maintain the pattern?

Take a look where that should take place: [printnil.com](http://printnil.com/#/filter/.mappen)

[image]

```
.container{
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0.1px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  float: left; 
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.container:after{
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;

}

.container .mix,
.container .gap{
  margin-bottom:1.5%;
}

.container .mix{
  display: none;
}

.container .mix:after{
  content: attr(data-myorder);
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container .mix:before{
  content: '';
}

.mix{
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:568px){
.container .mix,
.container .gap{
  width: 49.5%;
  margin-bottom:1%;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1024px){    
.container .mix,
.container .gap{
  width: 33%;
  margin-bottom:0.5%;
}
}
```

Comment: why don't you set the wrapper background to gray? then using white borders to generate your image?

Comment: it seems illogical to solve this in the way u r trying. change ur background-color to be what u want, then set the borders of them to be white. it will provide the same separation with far less effort.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this is the result you are looking for.

```css
.container {
font-size: 0.1px;
background: #f2f2f2;
width: 100%;
}

.container .mix {
width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container" class="container">
  <div class="mix" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0600/1373/products/agenda-cove_grande.jpg" alt="Agenda" height="100" width="100"/>
  </div>
  <div class="mix  mappen" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0600/1373/products/agenda-cove_grande.jpg" alt="Agenda" height="100" width="100"/>
  </div>
  <div class="mix" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0600/1373/products/agenda-cove_grande.jpg" alt="Agenda" height="100" width="100"/>
  </div>
  <div class="mix" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0600/1373/products/agenda-cove_grande.jpg" alt="Agenda" height="100" width="100"/>
  </div>
  <div class="mix" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0600/1373/products/agenda-cove_grande.jpg" alt="Agenda" height="100" width="100"/>
  </div>
  <div class="mix" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0600/1373/products/agenda-cove_grande.jpg" alt="Agenda" height="100" width="100"/>
  </div>
  <div class="mix" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0600/1373/products/agenda-cove_grande.jpg" alt="Agenda" height="100" width="100"/>
  </div>
</div>
```